# Products of three primes that bound RSA numbers

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Let $N$ be some number.  Let $R$ and $S$ be [semiprimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime) (ie, each is a product of two prime numbers) such that $R \le N \le S$.

For quite a few numbers $N$ we can find $R, S$ such that  $S-R$ is small; eg, for $N=50$, we have $7\cdot7 = 49 < 50 < 51 = 3\cdot17$, giving $S-R=2$.

For $N=10240579048185725616$ and certain other large numbers too numerous to mention we can quickly (via [prime quadruplets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_quadruplet)) find semiprimes $R, S$ such that  $S-R=12$.  But what about products of three primes?  How small can the interval be made?

The challenge in this puzzle is to find $U_k, V_k$, each the product of three primes, such that  $U_k \le N_k \le V_k$, given that $N_k$ is the [RSA number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers) with *k* decimal digits, while minimizing  $\Delta_k = V_k-U_k$.  Find best solutions for $k\in\{100, 160, 320, 480\}$.

For example, [RSA-100](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-100)

$$= 15226050279225333605356183781326374297180681149613806886579\\08494580122963258952897654000350692006139 = 37975227936943673922808872755445627854565536638199 × 40094690950920881030683735292761468389214899724061$$

If we let

$$U = 6246644847868435165458917\cdot1150435884651666110524532974697443\cdot211874175165550696134616092679587435515153$$

and

$$V = 6246644847868435165458967 \cdot 1150435884651666110524532974697441\cdot211874175165550696134616092679587435515309$$

then we obtain $U \le N \le V$ and

$$\Delta_{100} = 1218738270442411472694284522980510595717360280370\\4967527962531133881349172780$$

which is about 75 orders of magnitude larger than achievable with a little more work.  But what is the best achievable (or, minimal) value for $\Delta_{100}$?

Comment: When a puzzle involves this much math, shouldn't it be in Mathematics rather then puzzling?

Comment: @TimCouwelier, solving the puzzle requires a little insight, which once achieved may make it seem trivial.  It might be laughed at in Mathematics.

Comment: This question is not a puzzle, but rather an exercise in wasting CPU time.

Comment: @jwpat7 Most people don't know all the number theory you're asking about; I'm pretty sure it would be treated as well as a specialist topic in Math.SE. (The place you're thinking of where it would be laughed at is Math Overflow.)

Answer (score 1):

The insight I mentioned in a comment is realizing that most numbers no larger than those mentioned in the question have relatively few factors.  More concretely, the [Erdős–Kac theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem) says (roughly) that if $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of n, the distribution of
    $\frac{\omega(n) - \log\log n}{(\log\log n)^{1/2}}$
 is standard normal.  Thus, numbers in the neighborhood of [RSA-320](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-320) average about $(\log\log n)^{1/2} \approx 6.6$ distinct prime factors, with standard deviation about 2.6, making it not at all unlikely there will be a number near RSA-320 having exactly three (not necessarily distinct) prime factors.  The following code uses linear search to look for tri-prime near-neighbors of RSA-100, 160, 320, and 480.  It runs for about 3 seconds on my i3-2120@3.30GHz system, to produce the output shown after the program.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Close triprimes - jw 8 Sep 2014
from gmpy import is_prime, mpz
# Note, will run ok without mpz, but is twice as fast with it.
# Ref http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2227/products-of-three-primes-that-bound-rsa-numbers

# Return a tuple of nfax factors if k appears to
# factor into that many primes; else return None
def testfaxtuple(k, nfax):
    fax = []
    for p in smallprimes:
        while k % p == 0:       # Factors don't have to be distinct
            fax.append(p)       #   Add factor to list
            k /= p              #   Divide factor out of k
            if is_prime(k):     # If k is prime we are done with k
                fax.append(k)
                if len(fax) == nfax:
                    return fax  # Right number of prime factors
                else:
                    return None # There are too few prime factors
            if len(fax) == nfax:
                return fax if k==1 else None
            if k==1:
                return None
    return None                 # No small prime divides k

# Search up or down from k to find a number with nfax prime factors
def searchfaxtuple(k, d, nfax):
    while k:
        t = testfaxtuple(k, nfax)
        if t:
            return k, t     # Return the number and its factor tuple
        k += d

primeLim = 162401 # <--- With checks to 13, we are ok below that Carmichael#
smallprimes = [2,3,5,7,11,13]+[x for x in range(17,primeLim,2) if 1==pow(2,x-1,x)==pow(3,x-1,x)==pow(5,x-1,x)==pow(7,x-1,x)==pow(11,x-1,x)==pow(13,x-1,x)]

n100 = mpz(1522605027922533360535618378132637429718068114961380688657908494580122963258952897654000350692006139)
n160 = mpz(2152741102718889701896015201312825429257773588845675980170497676778133145218859135673011059773491059602497907111585214302079314665202840140619946994927570407753)
n320 = mpz(21368106964100717960120874145003772958637679383727933523150686203631965523578837094085435000951700943373838321997220564166302488321590128061531285010636857163897899811712284013921068534616772684717323224436400485097837112174432182703436548357540610175031371364893034379963672249152120447044722997996160892591129924218437)
n480 = mpz(302657075295090869739730250315591803589112283576939858395529632634305976144571441696598170401251852159138533455982172343712313383247732107268535247763784105186549246199888070331088462855743520880671299302895546822695492968577380706795842802200829411198422297326020823369315258921162990168697393348736236081296604185145690639952829781767901497605213955485328141965346769742597479306858645849268328985687423881853632604706175564461719396117318298679820785491875674946700413680932103)

for kfax in [3]:
    for n, digi in ((n100,100),(n160,160),(n320,320),(n480,480)):
        hik, hit = searchfaxtuple(n, +1, kfax)
        lok, lot = searchfaxtuple(n, -1, kfax)
        print 'n+{}: {}'.format(hik-n, hit)
        print 'n-{}: {}'.format(n-lok, lot)
        print '{}_Delta_{} = {}'.format(kfax, digi, hik-lok)
```

In each section of the output shown below, `n` represents an RSA number; eg, in the first line, `n+118` refers to a triprime equal to RSA-100 plus 118, and in the next line, `n-93` is a triprime equal to  RSA-100 minus 93, so $\Delta_{100} = 211$.

```
n+118: [13, 2953, mpz(39662534265610809360379754047582313415771916824126199918151254124361743292582586096381785164813L)]
n-93: [2, 75211, mpz(10122222998780320435412495367251049911037402208196810896397524927072655351337921963901559284493L)]
3_Delta_100 = 211
n+61: [2, 14519, mpz(74135308999204136025071120645802928206411377809961980169794671698399791487666476192334563667383809477322746301797135281427071928686646468097663303083117653L)]
n-70: [3, 1319, mpz(544033637280487667903971493887496949521802777064866307852033782354847901243077871031845099765855713824235003060799902527692523291686338170487729844560922519L)]
3_Delta_160 = 131
n+214: [11, 11, mpz(176595925323146429422486563181849363294526275898577963001245340525884012591560637141201942156625627631188746462786946811291756101831323372409349462897825265817338014972828793503479905244766716402622505987077689959486257125408530435565591308740005042768854308800768879173253489662414218570617545437984800765215949786931L)]
n-224: [13, 52967, mpz(31032539802141998370713948372794923048803506659048861371086912175551926415110187757087410014292935577266307064917373174540174489372323446763705246097551098091406550394530533545445667236373260977760206608231250640961988106055050507069621794059785570660151780084977488712077145638070904012868277923403920427364977503L)]
3_Delta_320 = 438
n+200: [3, 106109, mpz(950774126276096183294945921381446762571545246168059443262838630195698059368421282821118442360377386018586338752233308339262184430625526918133036932977045947049886582664643810707506629521666465240684262732647707617310165234420519487180926538436354475738540234808925486588681635303203907204533053585577836882503225253106681619695563938239299517807832686153949058563511011452366526580713058739184326135349574123004434448558166804769056335520764178595660391647191959672602115689L)]
n-169: [2, 3, mpz(50442845882515144956621708385931967264852047262823309732588272105717662690761906949433028400208642026523088909330362057285385563874622017878089207960630684197758207699981345055181410475957253480111883217149257803782582161429563451132640467033471568533070382887670137228219209820193831694782898891456039346882767364190948439992138296961316916267535659247554690327557794957099579884476440974878054830947903980308938767451029260743619899352886383113303464248645945824450068946821989L)]
3_Delta_480 = 369
```

Suppose the last seven lines of the program are replaced with the following eight:

```
print '#f   D100  D160  D320  D480'
for kfax in range(2,9):
    ro = []
    for n, digi in ((n100,100),(n160,160),(n320,320),(n480,480)):
        hik, hit = searchfaxtuple(n, +1, kfax)
        lok, lot = searchfaxtuple(n, -1, kfax)
        ro.append(int(hik-lok))
    print '{}:  {:5} {:5} {:5} {:5}'.format(kfax, *ro)
```

With that code, the program computes and prints $\Delta$ values for 2-factor, 3-factor, ... and 8-factor cases for four RSA numbers.  This took about 80 seconds of computation.

```
#f   D100  D160  D320  D480
2:     56   132   626   420
3:    211   131   438   369
4:     54    11    98  1434
5:    106   155   303   302
6:    341    75  1286   319
7:     76   836   284  3244
8:    100   417   620  2628
```

Eg, this shows there is a pair of quad-factor numbers that bound RSA-160 and differ by only 11.

Comment: Note, most of the numbers in the last table are likely to not be optimal because many 3rd, 4th, 5th... factors will exceed the largest test divisor in `smallprimes`.  Eg, with `primeLim=9999999` instead of `999999`, line 4 of the table reads `4:   39   6  98  1113` and line 7 reads `7:  76  677  41  2404`.  Also, test division methods get proportionally slower as `#f` increases, suggesting use of better factoring methods.

Comment: A big -1 from here, the "trick" is to use a bunch of formulas other people have created, on top of plenty CPU time. And you can't even produce optimal solutions.

Comment: @eBusiness, the Erdős–Kac theorem was mentioned to show the accuracy of the intuition there will be lots of 3-factor numbers near an RSA number, and that linear search is feasible ***without using a lot of CPU time.***  Granted, the program shown doesn't check or guarantee optimality.  It would take perhaps 4 more lines of code to check for optimality (which has a reasonable chance of occurring, even without any special measures) but would require a full-blown factoring method to guarantee it

Comment: For 100 and 160 digit numbers a full factoring could take an awful lot of time on a desktop computer. For 320 and 480 digits, well, the RSA numbers themselves haven't been factored yet, not even by people with big clusters. If this is to remotely resemble a puzzle you should at least cherry pick numbers so that an optimal solution can be proven without excessive CPU time consumption.